# Как в JS заранее проверить входящие типы параметров, то что сейчас есть в PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

```
// php
function data(int $number, string $string, bool $status) {}

// JS, здесь нужно проверить типы параметров
function data(number, str, status) {}
```

Если типы не соответствуют, то выдавать ошибку и не выполнять функцию

Comment: Посмотреть в сторону Typescript.

Comment: Да, согласен, что только TypeScript. Иначе можно костылять и велосипедить долго

Comment: Если для одной конкретной функции - то штатными средствами, если для всех - то типизированный Язык на основе JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В чистом JS валидировать входящие данные как на примере не получится.

---

Если вам нужно понимать типы данных, с которыми вы работаете во время разработки, то стоит посмотреть в сторону [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).

---

Если вам нужна валидация для вывода ошибок при неправильно передаваемых данных, то стоит посмотреть в сторону библиотек для валидации схем, например:

- [joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi)
- [Ajv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv)
- [jsonschema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonschema)

Пример подобного кода на joi:

```
function data({ number, str, status }) {}

const schema = joi.object({
  number: joi.number().required(),
  str: joi.string().required(),
  status: joi.boolean().required(),
});

const request = {
  number: 1,
  str: 'str',
  status: true,
};

// синхронно

const { value, error } = schema.validate(request);

if (!error) {
  data(value);
} else {
  // обработка ошибки
}

// асинхронно

try {
 const value = await schema.validateAsync(request);
 data(value);
} catch (error) {
  // обработка ошибки
}
```